# Internationalized drop downs using Spring 3

Tags: spring, select, internationalization

**Story**

I have a select control that represents user access level. I'm looking for a way to internationalize it. The label should be loaded from a message resource and the value should be used as is. I prepare all my drop down lists in controllers using a simple SelectOption class that has a label and a value properties. This way, my select's look consistent accross all jsp's.

**Problem**

I've found some examples but they are based on logic within jsp. Developer loops through his labels and manually constructs the option tag using a message resource. While this works, there just has to be a better way. I've also found some comments that Spring 3 will have support for internationalizing option labels but I can't find anything concrete on that.

**Controller logic**

```
Collection<SelectOption> optionList = new ArrayList<SelectOption>();
optionList.add(new SelectOption("-SELECT-", "-"));  
optionList.add(new SelectOption("Administrator", "ADMIN"));
optionList.add(new SelectOption("Editor", "EDIT"));
bean.setFilterUserAccessLevelOptionList(optionList);
```

**JSP logic**

```
<form:select path="filterUserAccessLevel"  items="${bean.filterUserAccessLevelOptionList}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"/>
```

**Questions**

1. I would like to add options in my controller in this way: optionList.add(new SelectOption("userAccessLevelAdministratorLabel", "ADMIN")); and have Spring convert userAccessLevelAdministratorLabel to a value from a message resource. Is this possible?
2. If Spring 3 cannot do this for me, how else can this be achieved without manually constructing the option tag within jsp?

**=== 2012-01-15 ==============================================================**

Still trying to work out a solution using aweigold's idea.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
SelectOptionListBuilder listBuilder;

    @RequestMapping("/userIndex/{pageNumber}")
public ModelAndView getUserList(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber, @ModelAttribute("userIndexBean") UserIndexBean phantomBean, Locale locale, Model model) {

    UserIndexBean bean = new UserIndexBean();

    // prepare filter form
    Collection<SelectOption> optionList = listBuilder.getUserAccessLevelOptionList(true, SortOrder.NONE, locale);
    bean.setFilterUserAccessLevelOptionList(optionList);
```

**SelectOptionListBuilderImpl**

```
@Component
public class SelectOptionListBuilderImpl implements SelectOptionListBuilder, MessageSourceAware {

private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override     
public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
} 


@Override
public List<SelectOption> getUserAccessLevelOptionList(boolean addSelectPrompt, SortOrder sortOrder, Locale locale) {
    List<SelectOption> optionList = new ArrayList<SelectOption>();

    if(addSelectPrompt) {
        optionList.add(new SelectOption(messageSource.getMessage("common.selectPromptLabel", null, locale), "-"));
    }
```

**messageSource mapping**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">    
<property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/i18n/messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
<property name="UseCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'common.selectPromptLabel' for locale 'en_CA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to do operations like this in a Controller outside of a jsp, I've been making my Controllers MessageSourceAware.  Spring will then inject a new MessageSource when they are swapped, and you can interrogate it much like Spring does.  In your example, you would do something like this:

```
@Controller
public class someController implements MessageSourceAware {
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @RequestMapping
    // Pass in the locale from the LocaleResolver
    public void someMapping(Locale locale){
        optionList.add(new SelectOption(
           messageSource.getMessage("userAccessLevelAdministratorLabel", null, locale),
           "ADMIN"))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying your idea. messageSource doesn't know about my message bundle. I tried to use an entry which is not related to my list but displays fine using spring:message. Same "No such message" error. In debugger, parent message source is null. Also, I can't find a way to inject locale into my list builder. Passing it as a parameter is the only way I was able to connect the pieces.

Comment: That is likely because your message bundle is not added to your MessageSource. Look at the ReloadableResourceBendleMessageSource, or ResourceMessageBundleSource classes.  Instantiate one of those as a bean, configured with your message bundle.  Also, consider making the component MessageSourceAware, that way the Spring context can swap it out with a new one.

Comment: I've added my messageSource mapping to the post. This mapping works because my `<spring:message` tags work fine. Can you think of any other reason why the `messageSource` in my `SelectOptionListBuilderImpl` would not be connected to the bundle? Also, would you mind explaining your last sentence from your comment?

Comment: Try using the MessageSourceAware interface (see my code in my original post here).  Spring provides the ability to change your MessageSource object during runtime, and it uses that interface to update anyone interrogating it directly.

Comment: I've implemented that interface and updated the post with my latest version of the list builder. I'm still getting the exception. The `messageSource` is set with an object of type `XmlWebApplicationContext`. That object has a list of `configLocations` where it has entries for application context and my spring security but it does not have an entry for my spring-servlet.xml where messsage source is defined.

Comment: Well, I've moved my message source bean definition from `spring-servlet.xml` to `applicationContext.xml` and this thing works, now. So this is something about those `configLocations`. I had followed someone else's example by placing message source in my `spring-servlet.xml`. Is there a rule of thumb on where this bean definition sould be?

Comment: That explains it... this was running in a different spring context, and the context itself is also a messagesource (hence why you were seeing it of type XmlWebApplicationContext instead of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource).  The rule of thumb would be to configure the messagesource you want in each context you start.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a spring roo project. They managed this kind of problem by creating `tagx` tags. This tags do what you already descibed (it contains a litte logic to load the messages from ressources and build the option tags). But because the logic is witten once and you can use this tags like normal tags in you `jspx` files, it feels like a tag that do what you want to have.

Comment: Thanks, Ralph. I have Spring Roo on my list of things but I'm trying to tackle one thing at a time. I'm getting old and I need to go slow. :)

Comment: @jacekn: only to make clear what I mean: I do NOT mean you should use ROO, I mean you should create a ROO project, and have a look how they did the tagx (`input.tagx` for example)

Comment: Thanks for clarification, Ralph. I actually started reading about roo itself, again. Got side tracked on pros and cons. I understand you only meant the tag. For now, I'm still playing so I'll move on. But frankly, I don't like the fact that my java class fetches the language dependent value. It works but to me, the tag is definitely a better place to handle this. When I work on an actual project, I'll definitely disect that tagx library.